# Video Capture intent in Android 30+ - Only owner is able to interact with pending item

Tags: android, video-capture, scoped-storage

I am trying to capture video on my app. It works below android API 30 but does not work on 30+. Seems like after sdk 30, android does not allow to read external storage entirely (scoped storage). I am currently having this error:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only owner is able to interact with pending item content://media/external_primary/video/media/57*

Now I have three questions:

1. How can I create video capture intent that saves video to apps internal storage? (Because scoped storage limitations are for external storage)
2. I can get content uri at `onActivityResult`, how to make this uri accessible and readable? (After I read this file, I will create a temporary file with it and edit this temp file.)
3. What is the proper way to capture a video with scoped storage limitations?

**video capture intent**

```
private fun dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
        takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        }
    }
}
```

**onActivityResult**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        when(requestCode){
            
            REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE -> {
                val videoUri: Uri? = data?.data
                setVideo(videoUri)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

videoUri looks like this:     *content://media/external_primary/video/media/57*

`setVideo` function normally gets the content uri, creates a temporary file from it, compresses, and gets a thumbnail from this file. And then I upload this file to the server.

Comment: Try using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, supplying a `Uri` from `FileProvider` to some filesystem location that your app can read and write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare s advice, I created a file with File provider and supply uri of this file with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Now I am able to do stuff with `videoUriForAddingCaptureVideo` and `videoPathForAddingCaptureVideo` variables. I am posting this answer to give a clue to fellow developers.

```
 private fun dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {

    val videosFolder = File(
        Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), application.applicationContext.resources
            .getString(R.string.app_name)
    )

    try {
        if (!videosFolder.exists()) {
            val isCreated: Boolean = videosFolder.mkdirs()
            if (!isCreated) {
                Log.e(TAG,"dispatchTakeVideoIntent : storage error")
                return
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val videoFileName = "VID_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val storageDir: File? = application.applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)


    try {
        val video = File.createTempFile(
            videoFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".mp4",  /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        )
        videoUriForAddingCaptureVideo = FileProvider.getUriForFile(application.applicationContext, application.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", video)
        videoPathForAddingCaptureVideo = video.absolutePath //Store this path as globe variable

        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUriForAddingCaptureVideo)
            takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
            }
        }

    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }


}
```